# Oracle 11g Accessing bind variable value

Tags: oracle11g

I was trying to view the bind variable value by running the below query. Since the data type is Timestamp, I think we have a bug which says **value_string** doesn't capture the value. So I tried the below workaround, still no luck.

```
 SELECT a.sql_text,
  b.name,
  b.POSITION,
  b.datatype_string,
  b.value_string,
  ANYDATA.ACCESSTIMESTAMP(VALUE_ANYDATA)
FROM v$sql_bind_capture b,
  v$sqlarea a
WHERE b.sql_id = 'fmsmcykjq17n1'
AND b.sql_id   = a.sql_id;
```

ANYDATA.ACCESSTIMESTAMP(VALUE_ANYDATA) returns null.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing SQL_ID from the where clause.. I just ran your SQL in TOAD  and got back multiple records with timestamp bind values. `WHERE  b.sql_id   = a.sql_id
and  ANYDATA.ACCESSTIMESTAMP(VALUE_ANYDATA)  is not null`;

Comment: Thanks Brian, But I would need the value for this particular SQL ID. Most of them is actually NULL.